# JDBC- cant retrive value and delete table in mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Im using JDBC with wamp and phpmyadmin. When an account is created i want to retrieve the id of that account. the table account i have id, name, balance.
its generates an SQLException:Column 'id' not found

```
sql = "INSERT INTO account (name, balance) VALUES ('" + name + "', " + 0 + ");";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        sql = "SELECT MAX(id) from account";
         ResultSet id = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
          while(id.next()){
          id_user  = id.getInt("id");
        }
        System.out.println(id_user);
```

And when i want ot remove an existing account it generates this execption: java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().
the code is:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM account WHERE id=" + id + "; ";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rs.next()){
          id_user  = rs.getInt("id");
        }
        if (id_user==id) {
            sql = "DELETE FROM contas WHERE id=" + id + "; ";
            stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            result = true;
        } else {
            result = false;
        }
```

Comment: Please show the create table statement.

Comment: do you mean this `Statement stmt = Connection conn.createStatement();`

Comment: RMI has nothing to do with this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I am aware you are doing something different, but some small tips for inserts:*

Java has a database independent way to fetch the generated keys of an INSERT.
That is a lot safer than taking the MAX afterwards or before, in a multi-user environment.

Scenario for wrong IDs:

1. first INSERT
2. second INSERT
3. first SELECT
4. second SELECT

Also use a PreparedStatement, for security (SQL injection) and escaping (if name contains single quote or backslash or so.

And try-withresources always closes things, even on return or exception.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO account (name, balance) VALUES (?, 0)";
try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql,
        Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)) {
    stmt.setString(1, name);
    int updateCount = stmt.executeUpdate(); // 1
    try (ResultSet id = stmt.getGeneratedKeys()) {
        id_user = 0;
        if (id.next()) { // 'if' as just 1 row inserted.
            id_user = id.getInt(1); // 1 key per row.
        }
    }
    System.out.println(id_user);
}
```

Comment: This is the proper way to retrieve auto-generated keys (when _sequences_ aren't supported in the DBMS), but wouldn't you need to pass `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` to either the `prepareStatement` or `executeUpdate` methods to allow `getGeneratedKeys()` to work?

Comment: @greenSocksRock thanks; I was pondering what all to throw into the answer, and forgot.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be using `PreparedStatement` with bind variables. Regardless, this

```
sql = "DELETE FROM contas WHERE id=" + id + "; ";
stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

is attempting to execute an `update` (specifically a `delete`, not a `select`), so you need something like

```
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

**or**

```
stmt.execute(sql);
```

[`Statement.executeQuery(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery%28java.lang.String%29) *returns a `ResultSet`*.

Comment: SQLException: Can not issue SELECT via executeUpdate().

Comment: @changez Only the `DELETE` is an update... not the `SELECT` (which is a query).

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

Solution was to order as ascending

```
 sql = "SELECT id from account ORDER BY id ASC";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            id_account = rs.getInt("id");
        }
 return id_account
```