# How to get auto incremented value from server after insert value operation

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite

I'm new in android, I'm inserting some values in MySQL database with json. When I insert value into DB, then user id fills with auto increment operation, I want to get this id after inserting operation and want to save it in local DB with sqlite. What should I do for it?

```
 params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("police_verified", uname));
 params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("timezone", p_mobile));
 params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fb_id", p_mobile));
 params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gid", p_mobile));
 params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("service_provider_bit", ""));


 // getting JSON Object
 // Note that create product url accepts POST method
 JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_users, "POST", params);

 // check log cat fro response
 Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

 // check for success tag
 try {
     int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

     if (success == 1) {
       //Save in to Local DB
       mHelper = new MyDbHelper(InsertInfoActivity.this);
       mHelper.open();
       boolean isSaved = AddData();


       if(isSaved=true) {
          InsertInfoActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(InsertInfoActivity.this, "Data inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
           }
        );
```

Comment: get the is from mysql on server and add it to response from server extract that is from json using json.getInt and store it in a contentprovider and sqlitedb locally. You will have to figure out each step .

Comment: hit the MySql database with php>> get the json reaponse (ids)>> Parse it and get values>> put it into your database according to your need..

Comment: JDBC has getGeneratedKeys,. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30214657/jdbc-cant-retrive-value-and-delete-table-in-mysql-database

Comment: thanks to all. means , i will have to put that value in response part of DB